# How to add a calendar header in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using this library, https://github.com/kizitonwose/CalendarView, to create a calendar view. I've followed the docs to add the month header.

I've add the following to `res/layout/calendar_month_header_layout.xml`:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/headerTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    tools:text="October 2019" />
```

also added the following to the activity xml:

```
<com.kizitonwose.calendarview.CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/month_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:cv_dayViewResource="@layout/calendar_day_layout"
    app:cv_monthHeaderResource="@layout/calendar_month_header_layout" />
```

I've also added the following code:

```
val monthHeader: com.kizitonwose.calendarview.CalendarView = findViewById(R.id.month_header)
        monthHeader.monthHeaderBinder = object : MonthHeaderFooterBinder<MonthViewContainer> {
            override fun create(view: View) = MonthViewContainer(view)
            override fun bind(container: MonthViewContainer, month: CalendarMonth) {
                println("TEST")
                container.textView.text = "${month.yearMonth.month.name.toLowerCase().capitalize()} ${month.year}"
            }
        }
```

However, nothing shows up for the activity. What am I missing? Thank you.

EDIT:

I notice the `println("TEST")` statement doesn't even get logged

Comment: Looks like there is a setup method that still needs to be called as well per the library docs. https://github.com/kizitonwose/CalendarView#step-2-1. Might be that

Comment: It's not that, I've tried it. It is necessary for the ```DayBinder``` but throws an error for the month header

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem was I had to have the `DayBinder` too. The `monthHeaderBinder` on it's own results in a null error. Below is the working code

```
val currentMonth = YearMonth.now()
val firstMonth = currentMonth.minusMonths(10)
val lastMonth = currentMonth.plusMonths(10)
val firstDayOfWeek = WeekFields.of(Locale.getDefault()).firstDayOfWeek

setContentView(R.layout.activity_calender_view)
var calendarView: com.kizitonwose.calendarview.CalendarView = findViewById(R.id.calendarView)
calendarView.dayBinder = object : DayBinder<DayViewContainer> {
    // Called only when a new container is needed.
    override fun create(view: View) = DayViewContainer(view)

    // Called every time we need to reuse a container.
    override fun bind(container: DayViewContainer, day: CalendarDay) {
        container.textView.text = day.date.dayOfMonth.toString()
    }
}

calendarView.setup(firstMonth, lastMonth, firstDayOfWeek)
calendarView.scrollToMonth(currentMonth)

calendarView.monthHeaderBinder = object : MonthHeaderFooterBinder<MonthViewContainer> {
    override fun create(view: View) = MonthViewContainer(view)
    override fun bind(container: MonthViewContainer, month: CalendarMonth) {
        container.textView.text = "${month.yearMonth.month.name.toLowerCase().capitalize()} ${month.year}"
    }
}
```

And the activity xml:

```
<com.kizitonwose.calendarview.CalendarView
            android:id="@+id/calendarView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cv_dayViewResource="@layout/calendar_day_layout"
            app:cv_monthHeaderResource="@layout/calendar_month_header_layout"/>
```